# voodoo3 failure

Tags: software-installation

Since 16.4 my voodoo3 has not allowed my workstation to work with anything except command line mode. I was able to upgrade to 18, 20, and 22 but only with command line. Even attempting a fresh install resulted in only a few dots and dashes across the top of the screen. I'd like to do a fresh install but without a working screen it is impossible. Any suggestions for an inexpensive replacement?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Ubuntu but asks for hardware recommendation.

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.